# How do I get out of 'screen' without typing 'exit'?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I `screen -r`'d into a Django server that's running and I can't simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and `exit` out of it.

Are there any alternative ways to get out of `screen`?

Currently, I manually close the tab on my local PC and `ssh` back in, but that's becoming tiresome.

Answer (score 791, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>.  See the [screen manual # Detach](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Detach).

Comment: yes, you generally do have a tl;dr moment with the `man` command. so when you have a tl;dr when doing `man command_name`, in this case `man screen`, you can generally access a shorter & pretty helpful version of the docs by   `--help` option, `command_name --help`, this case `screen --help`.

Comment: Here's a [screen quick reference](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference) and a [combined screen & tmux cheat sheet](http://www.mechanicalkeys.com/files/os/notes/tm.html) you may find handy.

Comment: `tmux --help` gives me new tmux session, so I'm like: "Oh sh~ why"

Comment: This does not work when using screen for connecting to a serial device.

Comment: @josch You should be able to use ctrl-a + k or ctrl-a + ctrl-k to kill the current screen window.  Ashish - The --help output only talks about command line options, it does not talk about the key bindings

Comment: While for most people, this answer seems like the easy escape, it isn't the correct answer as it doesn't "exit" the screen session. Ctrl+A,K does, as mentioned by @Aner

Comment: @Trutane the old link is dead, did it look like this one: [combined screen & tmux cheat sheet](http://www.dayid.org/comp/tm.html)

Comment: @Colin yes, with some differences at the bottom of the table. The [last archive of that mechanicalkeys.com page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150822091205/http://www.mechanicalkeys.com/files/os/notes/tm.html) is from 2015, and it includes links to a couple other resources, one of which is still alive

Answer (score 179):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> - Exit screen and terminate all programs in this screen. It is helpful, for example, if you need to close a tty connection.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> or - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> - "minimize" screen and `screen -r` to restore it.

Comment: I'm just clarifying for future readers. That's Ctrl-A followed by Ctrl-\, and Ctrl-A followed by Ctrl-D.

Comment: @Julian Detaching doesn't need Ctrl on both, just on ctrl+a. Works for me and if you do "ctrl+a" and then write ":help" you can see that it says that both ctrl+d and d works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it specifies both detaching and exiting.

Comment: Ctrl-A -> Ctrl-D just exits from the session for me, leaving it running in the background. Ctrl-A -> \ will exit the session completely (on Oracle Linux 6).

Comment: To quit, it's `Ctrl-a` + `\ `, not `Ctrl-a` + `Ctrl-\ ` ! The key bindings can be viewed by pressing: `Ctrl-a` + `?`

Comment: Any hint on how to get to use `C-a` + `C-\ ` on keyboards where `\ ` is not on the 'standard' position but under some `alt-[key]` combination (Spanish keyboard in my case?) Trying `Ctrl-Alt-[key]` does not work :(

Comment: At least on a Mac it's really C-a + C-\. C-a + \ does not work. On a German keyboard this means C-a + C-A-S-7.

Comment: @feklee on my machines, to quit on linux, screen key is `Ctrl-a + \ ` on macos it is `Ctrl-a + Ctrl+\ `

Answer (score 112):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Doing this will detach you from the `screen` session which you can later resume by doing `screen -r`.
- You can also do: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then type <kbd>:</kbd>. This will put you in screen command mode. Type the command `detach` to be detached from the running screen session.

Comment: It's simply "Ctrl-a" then "d"

Comment: @Kostyantyn It works (as the man pages says 'For your convenience') both with and without the Ctrl for the d - so "Ctrl-a" "Ctrl-d" works, and so does "Ctrl-a" "d". Take your pick.

Answer (score 74):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>k</kbd> will "kill" the current screen session.

Comment: This is the correct answer to what the question is asking - "exit" screen NOT detach from it.

Answer (score 20):

To terminate the screen session use

```
Ctrl + a followed by k
```

To detach session and restore later use

```
Ctrl + a followed by d
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the previous answers, you can also do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, and then enter colon (<kbd>:</kbd>), and you will notice a little input box at the bottom left. Type 'quit' and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to leave the current screen session. Note that this will **remove** your screen session.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>K</kbd> will only kill the current **window** in the current **session**, not the **whole** session. A screen session consists of windows, which can be created using subsequent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>C</kbd>. These windows can be viewed in a list using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd>.