# Where is /var/lib/docker on Mac/OS X

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I´m looking for the folder `/var/lib/docker` on my Mac after installing docker for Mac.

With `docker info`  I get

```
    Containers: 5
     ...
    Server Version: 1.12.0-rc4
    Storage Driver: aufs
     Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
     Backing Filesystem: extfs
     Dirs: 339
     Dirperm1 Supported: true
    ...
    Name: moby
    ID: LUOU:5UHI:JFNI:OQFT:BLKR:YJIC:HHE5:W4LP:YHVP:TT3V:4CB2:6TUS
    Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
    Debug Mode (client): false
    ....
```

But I don´t have a directory `/var/lib/docker` on my host.

I have checked `/Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/` but couldn´t find anything there. Any idea where it is located?

Comment: It is located inside the vm that docker instantiates to provide the necessary Linux environment.

Comment: Could it be that File: /Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

Comment: That is the disk image underlying the vm, yes.  But if you want to muck about with the contents of that directory you would need to log into the vm itself.  You can find instructions for doing so at https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/installation/mac/

Comment: thx, risizing this file works with  qemu-img resize Docker.qcow2 +5g https://forums.docker.com/t/consistently-out-of-disk-space-in-docker-beta/9438

Comment: Do you know where to find this directory?@christian

Comment: @jason not really, i think it´s embedded in /Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-‌​linux/Docker.qcow2

Answer (score 56, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642236/2380457)

When using Docker for Mac Application, it appears that the containers are stored within the VM located at:

> ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

Comment: **If you came here from Google**, scroll down to find the right answer.

Comment: I think this was the answer. But I'm using v20.10 now, theres nothing `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux` directory.

Answer (score 184):

As mentioned in the above answers, you will find it in:
`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

Once you get the tty running you can navigate to `/var/lib/docker`

Comment: one slight modification (below your home, not below root): "screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty"

Comment: Works! But how do I exit from that shell? Ctrl + d, `exit`, and `logout` won't work.

Comment: You can detach from the screen with ctrl + a + d

Comment: Detaching will still keep the screen session running. You can see this by running `screen -ls`. If you have already detached, run `screen -X quit`. If you have multiple screen sessions, you'll need `-S` to specify the session name. If you haven't detached do press ctrl + a, :, q, u, i, t, ENTER. Those two just run the screen quit command in the session.

Comment: I think it may be located at ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty now.

Comment: @RichardCollette, on my machine, both are just symlinks to /dev/ttys000

Comment: @Mikjagger after running the command, it outputs [screen is terminating] every time. Cannot get into the docker vm. And just like "@doesntmatter" said, tty file has a line "/dev/ttys000 "

Comment: For me, when trying to `screen`, it would just exit immediately. `ls -l` showed the `tty` to be a symlink to `/dev/ttys013`, but that mount point didn't exist.. Instead I used the command from https://gist.github.com/BretFisher/5e1a0c7bcca4c735e716abf62afad389 to get a shell into the docker vm: `docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1`

Comment: I think this was the answer. But I'm using v20.10 now, theres nothing `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty` directory.

Comment: This answer is outdated. As of 13 August 2021, the answer by RicarHincapie is correct. Keep scrolling until you find it.

Comment: No such paths on Mac M1 Moterey am afraid though voumes can be previewed via Docker app's Dashboard on Macs or Visual Code Studio with a docker extention installed (left hand side menu).
I'd rather have direct linux access although this shouldn't be a problem on proper Linux UAT or PRODuction hosts under the default /var/lib/docker/volumes path. Since it's only affecting macOS which is purely dev in my case so no need to back up databases.

Answer (score 114):

As of 2021 is the dance going, Mac Users get easily to the VM with the documented methods, and hence to the volumes.

There's a way [Rocky Chen](https://rocky-chen.medium.com/docker-unable-to-access-to-volume-with-screen-for-mac-9d016f5420e6) found to get inside the VM in Mac. With this you can actually inspect the famous `/var/lib/docker/volumes`.

`docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh`

Let examine the method:

- **-it** goes for Keep STDIN open even if not attached + Allocate pseudo-TTY
- **--privileged** "gives all capabilities to the container. Allows special cases like running [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#:%7E:text=The%20%2D%2Dprivileged%20flag%20gives,like%20running%20Docker%20within%20Docker.)" .
- **--pid** defines to use the host VM namespace.
- **debian** the actual image to use.
- **nsenter** a [debian's tool](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/nsenter.1.en.html) to run programs in different namespaces
- **-t** is the target PID
- **-m** mount the provided PID namespace.
- **-u** enter the Unix Time Sharing (UTS) namespace.
- **-n** enter the provided PID network namespace.
- **-i** enter the provided PID IPC namespace.

Once run, go to `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`and you'll find your volumes.

The next question to address for me is:

**How to take those volumes and back them up in the host?**

I appreciate ideas in the comments!

**UPDATE FOR VSCODE USERS**

If you downloaded the Official Docker extension, sun will shine for you.

[image: Docker Extension]

Just inspect the volumes in Visual Studio Code. Right-click the files you want to have in your local, and download them. That easy!

**2nd UPDATE**

As of July 2021, Docker Desktop for Mac is announcing we will be able to access volumes directly from the GUI, but only for Pro and Team accounts.

[image]

Comment: Also works for adding files to the volume. After opening the volume through "Inspect in Visual Studio Code", I drag-and-drop'd files into the volume

Comment: ***When in VS Code, right on the volume and select "Explore in a remote container"

Comment: I was able to browse the volume using the `debian nsenter` approach, the VSCode plugin works like a charm, and the Docker Desktop wants me to upgrade to Pro or Team plan. As of this moment, this is **The Correct Answer**.

Comment: I have docker compose running, it uses volumes as well. However this tab only loads for eternity. No single volume i loaded.

Comment: I could not edit any files with this unfortunately. I tried to install nano with `apk update` but it says the files are read only

Comment: For backup: `docker run -v <volume_name>:/volume --rm loomchild/volume-backup backup - > <volume_name>.tar.bz2`

Comment: For restore: `cat <volume_name>.tar.bz2 | docker run -i -v <volume_name>:/volume --rm loomchild/volume-backup restore -`

Comment: Using vs code docker extension works like a magic. 

> Just open vs code and into the docker icon
> open the volumes tab
> right-click on the volume you create and click "inspect in vs code" this will load the container files in a new vscode window.

Comment: "docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh" from this answer worked for me to get inside of Docker VM

Answer (score 60):

The other answers here are outdated if you're using Docker for Mac.

Here's how I was able to get into the VM. Run the command:

`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

This is the default path, but you may need to first do:
`cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms`

and then `ls` to see which directory your VM is in and replace the "0" accordingly.

When you're in, you might just see a blank screen. Hit your "Enter" key.

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847691/how-do-i-get-out-of-a-screen-without-typing-exit) explains that to exit from the VM you need to "Ctrl-a" then "d"

Comment: Not fully working, because if you exit VM and enter it again, you'll get messed up shell.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I end up with a messed up shell.  I have gone through and killed previous screen sessions and then tried again.  When hitting enter I get random characters.  if you hit enter again, new random characters.  And so on

Comment: to quit screen program use ctl-a then ctl-\
`/var/lib/docker` is in VM where you are after run `screen`, so e.g. `ls /var/lib/docker` etc.

Comment: I got rid of the messy shell by ```screen -ls``` and then ```screen -X -S SESSION_NAME quit``` for every session. If you disconnect with ctr-A then D you can reconnect to the screen with ```screen -R``` and get a clean shell as well.

Comment: This answer is outdated. As of 13 August 2021, the answer by RicarHincapie is correct. Keep scrolling until you find it.

Answer (score 15):

Just as @Dmitriy said:

`screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`

and can use `ctrl a` + `d` to detach the screen

and use `screen -dr` to re-attach the screen again(since if you simply attach screen again, the terminal text will be garbled.)

[Reference](https://williambert.online/2017/12/Docker-for-Mac-the-Missing-Manual/)

or if you want to exit, use `ctrl + a` + `k`,then choose `y` to kill the screen.

Comment: This answer is outdated. As of 13 August 2021, the answer by RicarHincapie is correct. Keep scrolling until you find it.

Answer (score 13):

I think the new version of docker (my version is 20.10.5) uses socket instead of TTY to communicate with the virtual machine so you can use the nc command instead of the screen command.

```
nc -U ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/debug-shell.sock
```

Comment: you should have debug-shell.sock in ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/ path. do you have it?

Comment: its a little janky but it works for me. Though I can't seem to find my volumes in this vm yet.

Answer (score 7):

some what of a zombie thread but as I just found it here is another solution that doesn't need screen nor messes up shell etc.

The path listed from a `docker volume inspect <vol_name>`

returns the path for the container, something like:

`"Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/coap_service_db_data/_data"`

the `_data` component being the last component of the path you setup in the `volumes:` section of the service using a given volume eg:

`volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` , obvs your mileage will vary.

To get there on the mac the easiest method I have found is to actually start a small container running and mount the root of the host to the `/docker` directory in the image, this gives you access to the volumes used on the host.

`docker run --rm -it -v /:/docker alpine:edge`

from this point you can cd to the volume

`cd /var/lib/docker/volumes/coap_service_db_data/_data`

Comment: This answer is outdated. As of 13 August 2021, the answer by RicarHincapie is correct. Keep scrolling until you find it.

Comment: `cd /docker/var/lib/docker/volumes/coap_service_db_data/_data`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the new version of docker for Mac has moved this to a UI element which you can see here. Clicking on that button which says CLI will launch a terminal which you can use to browse the docker file system.[image: Docker CLI Button]

Comment: The icons are visible on the Containers pane

Comment: Is this only on a paid version? I see nothing like this on my Free Plan. I do see a Volumes pane, but that states explicitly--when I click on a volume--that I need a Pro or Team plan to play.

Comment: How this answers OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -a bash
ls /var/lib/docker
```

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS I use the following steps:

1. login into docker virtual-machine (on MacOS docker can be run only inside virtual machine, in my case I have VirtualBox tool with docker VM): `docker-machine ssh`
2. as soon as I logged-in I need to switch to super user from `docker` user: `sudo -i`
3. now I'm able to check `/var/lib/docker` directory

Answer (score 0):

This path comes from Docker Host (not from MacOS)
before "Docker for Mac Application" times, where there was a VirtualBox VM "default" and inside this VM, the mentioned path exists (for sure), now in "Docker for Mac Application" times there is a Docker.qcow2 image, which is qemu base vm.
To jump inside this VM @mik-jagger way is ok (but there are few more)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the file:

```
/var/run/docker.sock
```

Is actually at:

```
/Volumes/{DISKNAME}/var/run/docker.sock
```

If you run this, it should prove it, as long as your running VirtualBox 5.2.8 or later and the share for `/Volumes`  is setup to be auto-mounted and permanent AND you generated the default docker-machine while on that version of Virtualbox:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -d --restart unless-stopped -p 9000:9000 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock portainer/portainer \
--no-auth
```

Then, access Portainer at:  192.168.99.100:9000 or localhost:9000

Answer (score 0):

Docker logs are not in /var/lib/docker on MacOS.

MacOs users can find the docker logs on this path;

/Users/Barrack.Kenya/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/log/host

- job_name: docker
  static_configs:

  - targets:

    - docker
      labels:
      job: dockerlogs
      **path**: (Please put the path)

  pipeline_stages:

  - docker: {}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).