# How do I delete Postgres docker volume?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a `docker-compose.yml` which I am using to deploy to a remote host from my local (Mac) machine using `docker context`. The compose config is as follows:

```
database:
    image: postgres:14.2
    restart: on-failure

    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

In order to persist data, I have defined a volume `./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`. This `db-data` folder does not exist in my local machine. I want delete this mount completely because I don't want any of the previously persisted data. I know I can define a new volume directory but I would like to use the same directory name (`db-data`). I have tried the following:

1. `docker compose down --volume --remove-orphans` - when I recreate new container, previously persisted data still exists
2. There is no folder called `./db-data` in my Mac working directory.
3. I tried searching `var/lib/docker` in my Mac. But that directory does not exists.
4. Docker for Mac app doesn't list any volumes
5. There is no `db-data` in the remote host where the database is deployed

Comment: That syntax should cause a directory named `db-data` to exist on the system running the Docker daemon, and you should be able to just delete it with `rm -rf`.  It will not create a named Docker volume; you will not be able to see this directory with `docker volume` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `docker inspect <container-id>` listed the mount directory for the container. The mount directory resembled absolute path of my local computer. For example it was like `/Users/<user-name>/dir/db-data`. When I saw this I assumed this had to be in the local computer due to the prefix `Users/<user-name>` but this path was actually found in the root of the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the directory for docker volumes is in the docker vm for MACOS.
[Where is /var/lib/docker on Mac/OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532483/where-is-var-lib-docker-on-mac-os-x)

You would have to follow this to see the volume